# Why does this keep give syntax error or $_end error?

Tags: php, sql, syntax, sql-update

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['update']))
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'XXXXX';
$dbpass = 'XXXXX';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
{
 $OrderID=addslashes ($_POST['OrderID']); 
 $trackingnumber= addslashes ($_POST['trackingnumber']);
 $trackingURL=addslashes ($_POST['trackingURL']); 
 $CustomerName=addslashes ($_POST['CustomerName']); 
 $LocationShipped=addslashes ($_POST['LocationShipped']); 
 $user_email=addslashes ($_POST['user_email']); 
 $ShipmentDate=addslashes ($_POST['ShipmentDate']);
 $ShipmentMode=addslashes ($_POST['ShipmentMode']);  
 $CurrentStatus=addslashes ($_POST['CurrentStatus']);
}
else
{
 $trackingnumber= $_POST['trackingnumber'];
 $trackingURL=$_POST['trackingURL']; 
 $OrderID=$_POST['OrderID']; 
 $CustomerName=$_POST['CustomerName']; 
 $user_email=$_POST['user_email']; 
 $LocationShipped=$_POST['LocationShipped']; 
 $ShipmentDate=$_POST['ShipmentDate'];
 $ShipmentMode=$_POST['ShipmentMode'];  
 $CurrentStatus=$_POST['CurrentStatus'];
}

$sql = "
    UPDATE
        ordertracking
    SET
        trackingnumber =$trackingnumber,
        `trackingURL` = '" . $trackingURL . "',
        `CustomerName` = '" . $CustomerName . "',
        `LocationShipped` = '" . $LocationShipped . "',
        `user_email` = '" . $user_email . "',
        `ShipmentDate` = '" . $ShipmentDate . "',
        `ShipmentMode` = '" . $ShipmentMode . "',
        `CurrentStatus` = '" . $CurrentStatus . "',
    WHERE
        OrderNo = $OrderID,

$result1 = mysql_query($query1);
mysql_select_db('XXXXXXX');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

---

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/buyerhel/public_html/ordertracking/backend/processeditship.php on line 46

Any help please ?

Not sure what the problem is but it is really frustrating since I am on my last step for the Edit Section of the my project and it is allowing me to update the table.
I purposely left out the quotes here - trackingnumber =$trackingnumber,
So that is not the problem..

The

Comment: Because you don't close the quote at the end of the declaration of `$sql`?

Comment: A piece of your query was (accidentally?) deleted by you. It ends with ` OrderNo = $OrderID,` implying there is another WHERE condition to follow

Comment: Look at the colours...

Answer (score 2):

There is no ending symbol `"` in your `$sql`. Should be:

```
$sql = "
    UPDATE
        ordertracking
    SET
        trackingnumber =$trackingnumber,
        `trackingURL` = '" . $trackingURL . "',
        `CustomerName` = '" . $CustomerName . "',
        `LocationShipped` = '" . $LocationShipped . "',
        `user_email` = '" . $user_email . "',
        `ShipmentDate` = '" . $ShipmentDate . "',
        `ShipmentMode` = '" . $ShipmentMode . "',
        `CurrentStatus` = '" . $CurrentStatus . "'
    WHERE
        OrderNo = $OrderID"; // < missing ";
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply..but now I get "Could not enter data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE 'OrderNo' = 12345888884' at line 12"

Comment: should not be a comma before WHERE

Comment: havent seen it, thank you @JeffHawthorne. Answer has been updated

Comment: Jeff, I owe you a beer :) Thank you all for your help! Will comeback with more questions now :)

Comment: @user2413575 you're new there so let me send you to read this part of faq: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0):

You've used `,` instead of `;` and forgot some `"`.

```
$sql = "
    UPDATE
        `ordertracking`
    SET
        `trackingnumber` = " . $trackingnumber . ",
        `trackingURL` = '" . $trackingURL . "',
        `CustomerName` = '" . $CustomerName . "',
        `LocationShipped` = '" . $LocationShipped . "',
        `user_email` = '" . $user_email . "',
        `ShipmentDate` = '" . $ShipmentDate . "',
        `ShipmentMode` = '" . $ShipmentMode . "',
        `CurrentStatus` = '" . $CurrentStatus . "',
    WHERE
        `OrderNo` = " . $OrderID; // ; instead of ,

$result1 = mysql_query($query1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems

1. Close the double qoutes
2. Remove the trailing comma after $OrderID

So change

```
$sql = "
UPDATE
    ordertracking
SET
    trackingnumber =$trackingnumber,
    `trackingURL` = '" . $trackingURL . "',
    `CustomerName` = '" . $CustomerName . "',
    `LocationShipped` = '" . $LocationShipped . "',
    `user_email` = '" . $user_email . "',
    `ShipmentDate` = '" . $ShipmentDate . "',
    `ShipmentMode` = '" . $ShipmentMode . "',
    `CurrentStatus` = '" . $CurrentStatus . "',
WHERE
    OrderNo = $OrderID,
```

to

```
$sql = "
UPDATE
    ordertracking
SET
    trackingnumber =$trackingnumber,
    `trackingURL` = '" . $trackingURL . "',
    `CustomerName` = '" . $CustomerName . "',
    `LocationShipped` = '" . $LocationShipped . "',
    `user_email` = '" . $user_email . "',
    `ShipmentDate` = '" . $ShipmentDate . "',
    `ShipmentMode` = '" . $ShipmentMode . "',
    `CurrentStatus` = '" . $CurrentStatus . "',
WHERE
    OrderNo = $OrderID";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace Line no 50

```
   OrderNo = $OrderID";
```

by this code